# Formatting a Dataframe Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I read a csv file that resulted into following DataFrame (the actual dataframe is much larger) -

```
df1 = 

Index     Country    Age         Height
0         Bob        nan         nan
1         nan        nan         nan
2         Bill       nan         nan
3         nan        nan         nan
4         Jack       nan         nan
5         nan        nan         nan
6         Mary       nan         nan
7         nan        nan         nan
8         USA        10          20
9         UK         5           10
10        Canada     12          15
11        Peru       20          25
```

I want to format the daraframe to have the following output -

```
df_formatted = 

Index      Name      Country      Age        Height
0          Bob       USA          10         20
1          Bill      UK           5          10
2          Jack      Canada       12         15
3          Mary      Peru         20         25
```

What would be an efficient way to accomplish that for a large dataframe? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the logic to matching Bob with USA, Bill with UK, etc....?

Comment: Is there a way to to know that Bob is from the USA, and Bill is from the UK, etc.?  Is there a list or something the tells us what strings are `Names` and what strings are `Countries`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming number of names are the same than number of countries:

```py
df = df.set_index("Index").dropna(how="all")
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.iloc[: len(df) // 2, [0]]
        .rename(columns={"Country": "Name"})
        .reset_index(drop=True),
        df[len(df) // 2 :].reset_index(drop=True),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Name Country   Age  Height
0   Bob     USA  10.0    20.0
1  Bill      UK   5.0    10.0
2  Jack  Canada  12.0    15.0
3  Mary    Peru  20.0    25.0
```